# .htaccess or between rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have an issue with my .htaccess redirects.

What i want to happen is that all requests to the root, index.php and item.php are redirected to their http equivalent, but every single other page is directed to it's https version.

This is to be used to prevent the slower loading of pages.

Here's what's in my htaccess at the moment:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC] .
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index.php|item.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R,L]  

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC] .
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index.php|item.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Ideally i need to have an OR inbetween the 2nd and third lines of each collective statement! But i can't work out how to do this!

Answer (score 0):

use [OR] at the end of the 2nd statement.

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC,OR]`

Comment: What i get now is a redirect loop :P

Comment: That's because your https directs to your non-https, and vice versa!

Comment: Just to get this straight, you want index.php and item.php to be ran through http, and anything else through https? (By the way, https won't make things slower)

Comment: Yeah that's what i would like as well as the root folder so `www.example.com/` :) I guess it makes the site look more professional and less lazy if i don't constantly use https

Comment: To be honest, https for everything is the best way to go, rather than mixed. It actually makes it look more professional, I'd say.

Comment: If i wanted to display insecure content e.g. from youtube, it's an inconvenience to change the link if i'm using a CMS

Comment: Actually, for that, I'd do //youtube.com/?v=123 strip out the http: part, it will default to whatever you are using client side :)

Comment: _Why_ do you want an `OR` between those conditions?  Using `and` (the default) seems more logical.